# How do I make these lifetimes match?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Say we have some code like this:

```rust
struct X {
    y: String,
}

trait Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self, x: &X);
}

type Stack<'a> = Vec<&'a X>;

struct Quux<'a> {
    stack: Stack<'a>,
}

fn bar(stack: &mut Stack, x: &X) {
    stack.push(x);
}

impl <'a>Foo for Quux<'a> {
    fn bar(&mut self, x: &X) {
        bar(&mut self.stack, x)
    }
}
```

The goal is to share the function `bar` between structs that implement `Foo`. It turns out that `bar` does some stuff with `self.stack` and so we can't easily implement a common definition on `Foo`.

This code won't compile, complaining the lifetimes of `Stack` and `&X` differ. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=0b0533e315d6f6eb790ba103c0780db6).

How can we make these lifetimes match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the question, actually. You need to make the lifetimes match. So your (non-trait) `bar` needs to have the signature

```
fn bar<'a>(stack: &mut Stack<'a>, x: &'a X)
```

Now, your trait is too general. It's making a promise that it can't keep. It says "if something implements `Foo`, then you can call `bar` on it with *any* reference to `X`". But that's not what you want. You need to restrict that to a *specific* lifetime of `x`. So let's parameterize that.

```
trait Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&mut self, x: &'a X);
}
```

Then we change the `impl`.

```
impl <'a>Foo<'a> for Quux<'a> {
    fn bar(&mut self, x: &'a X) {
        bar(&mut self.stack, x)
    }
}
```

Because now we're making the right guarantee. `Quux<'a>` doesn't implement `Foo`. It specifically implements `Foo<'a>` for the particular lifetime `'a`.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=76616ee972244f924923a8f74c3a0ef8)

Complete code:

```
struct X {
    y: String,
}

trait Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&mut self, x: &'a X);
}

type Stack<'a> = Vec<&'a X>;

struct Quux<'a> {
    stack: Stack<'a>,
}

fn bar<'a>(stack: &mut Stack<'a>, x: &'a X) {
    stack.push(x);
}

impl <'a>Foo<'a> for Quux<'a> {
    fn bar(&mut self, x: &'a X) {
        bar(&mut self.stack, x)
    }
}

fn main(){}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was missing in my understanding.